# selenium .get method fails to load a link

Tags: python, selenium

so I have started working on selenium, and this is my first time working with it, the code provided below opens chrome but doesnt open the url mentioned in the .get function.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

# open chrome and access the page
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe")
driver.get('https://dex.onxrp.com/?project=XREEFS')
time.sleep(5)
driver.close()
```

I have installed the selenium pip library, do i need something else as well for it to load the link?

Comment: What happens when you running this? Any error? Do browser opens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [selenium3](/questions/tagged/selenium3) the default argument which can be passed within `webdriver.Chrome()` is the value of the *KEY* *`executable_path`* i.e. the logical/absolute path of the [*ChromeDriver*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) executable but not of [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) executable.

---

### Solution

Ideally, your line of code will be:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe')
```

Comment: File "c:\Users\aadit\OneDrive\Desktop\testing_py\web_scrap_test.py", line 5
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Users\aadit\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
                                                                                            ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: use it as a raw string:  `driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\aadit\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")` or use double slash in lieu of single slash` as single slash acts as escape character

Comment: @AadityaThakkar Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: yes works, thanks